# Packages not showing up in aptitude

Tags: debian, apt, repository

I have a very strange problem on my server that I have just upgraded from Debian 7 to 9. It does not list some packages that should be present in its repositories...

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ stable main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ stable main contrib non-free

deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ stable-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ stable-updates main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ stable/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ stable/updates main

deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main
$ aptitude update
Hit http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-backports InRelease
Hit http://security.debian.org stable/updates InRelease
Ign http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian stable InRelease
Hit http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian stable-updates InRelease
Hit http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian stable Release
Deleting obsolete downloaded files       

$ aptitude search php5-
i A php5-cli                                                                        - command-line interpreter for the php5 scripting language
i A php5-common                                                                     - Common files for packages built from the php5 source
i   php5-curl                                                                       - CURL module for php5
i A php5-json                                                                       - JSON module for php5
v   php5-mhash                                                                      -
i A php5-readline                                                                   - Readline module for php5
$
```

It lists the already installed packages alright - but there should be a *few* more... Does anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debian's on [php7.0 now.](https://packages.debian.org/stable/php/)

If you need to install old php5, I think it might be possible to add `jessie` (Debian 8) to your apt sources, and carefully install the php5 packages from there, but there will probably be conflicts if they try to pull in XML libraries etc that are older than Debian 9's version.

Comment: Oh, wow, how did I miss this? When I saw php5 packages still being used I didn't consider that this might onle be because they were installed before the system upgrade. Thanks for pointing this out. I will try to get what I need from jessie or fix things for php7.